# DBCC CHECKDB WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS fails when run on Secondary replica

Tags: sql-server-2019, dbcc-checkdb

Create the simplest database possible:

```
CREATE DATABASE DatabaseCheck
```

Add this database to an Availability Group, where secondary is not readable

On primary run:

```
DBCC CHECKDB ('DatabaseCheck') WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS
```

It succeeds:

> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database
> 'DatabaseCheck'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
> messages, contact your system administrator.

Run the same DBCC command on secondary. It fails even though no errors were found:

> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database
> 'DatabaseCheck'. Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 1 A severe error
> occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be
> discarded.

- Removing WITH `EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS` makes the error go away
- Making the secondary replica readable makes the error go away
- Doing a failover and checking the new primary makes the error go away.
  Checking the new secondary shows the error again.

Any idea what is this about? Checking [DBCC CHECKDB documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#perform-logical-consistency-checks-on-indexes) doesn't say anything about EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS being unsupported on non-readable secondary replica. Looks like a bug in the command itself to me.

One thing I noticed in the command output is that it checks statistics like here:

> Verified integrity of statistics 'sys.sysrscols.clst'. Verified
> integrity of statistics 'sys.sysrowsets.clust'. Verified integrity of
> statistics 'sys.sysrowsets._WA_Sys_00000002_00000005'. Verified
> integrity of statistics 'sys.sysrowsets._WA_Sys_00000003_00000005'.
> Verified integrity of statistics
> 'sys.sysrowsets._WA_Sys_00000006_00000005'. Verified integrity of
> statistics 'sys.sysrowsets._WA_Sys_00000004_00000005'. Verified
> integrity of statistics 'sys.sysrowsets._WA_Sys_00000005_00000005'.
> Verified integrity of statistics
> 'sys.sysrowsets._WA_Sys_00000008_00000005'.

These are absent when run on secondary

Reproduced on:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU23) (KB5030333) - 15.0.4335.1 (X64)
> Sep 21 2023 17:28:44    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 
> (Build 17763: )

**Edit:**

The only message in error log is this:

> DBCC CHECKDB (DatabaseCheck) executed by Domain\user found 0 errors
> and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time: 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds.
> Internal database snapshot has split point LSN =
> 00000034:000001b1:0001 and first LSN = 00000034:000001af:0002.

There are no recent dumps in sys.dm_server_memory_dumps

Comment: Do you have any related messages in the SQL Server error log?

Comment: @DanGuzman I would need to double check (no access to the server right now), but I believe there was nothing beyond what I provided

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_memory_dumps ORDER BY creation_time DESC;` and see if there is a relevant memory dump. This is almost certainly a bug in AG.